# Sonarqube 5.3: Error installing on Oracle 12 - columns missing

Tags: oracle, installation, sonarqube, sonarqube5.3

I am trying to install Sonarqube 5.3 using an Oracle 12.1.0.2.0 database.

Oracle user is created with all permission granted (grant all) and "revoke select any" options.
Sonar is started with "./sonar.sh start" but the initial schema creation fails AFTER table creation ON insert to table "GROUPS":

```
2016.01.15 09:42:25 ERROR web[jruby.rack] initialization failed
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::JDBCError: ORA-00904: "VERSION": invalid identifier
: INSERT INTO groups (name, description, created_at, updated_at, displayname, created, lastmodified, version, id) VALUES('sonar-administrators', 'System administrators', TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-15 09:42:25:478000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6
'), TO_TIMESTAMP('2016-01-15 09:42:25:478000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF6'), NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, ?)
```

Compared the table structure with the statement I noticed that not all columns have been created: Columns DISPLAYNAME, CREATED, LASTMODIFIED, VERSION are missing!

1. Why are these not created?
2. If I create them manually, sonar fails to start afterwards. Is there any way to re-init the initial data?

Using sonars embedded database works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: After further investigation i found out that we have some public synonyms on our database having the same name than some tables to be created by sonar.
It seems sonar is not creating its own tables when an object with the same name exists. Dropping the synonym, clearing the schema and restarting sonar to recreate the schema did NOT sole it -> same error. I think that might not be the reason then... any idea?

Comment: Trying to create the schema with initial data on a local Oracle XE database now and migrate it afterwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

It seems database configuration and permissions in combination with public synonyms on our database caused this issue.
The problem has been solved by proceeding the following steps:

- wipe out partly generated schema including all containing objects
- install Sonarqube 5.3 on a newly/clean Oracle XE 11 database and create basic configuration
- stop Sonarqube & export database schema
- import database schema on Oracle 12 database

After starting up Sonarqube I realized a problem with Oracle JDBC driver 12.1.0.1 producing a NullPointerException while starting.
Basically this is a bug in the driver itself and already fixed by Oracle -> use ojdbc-driver 12.1.0.2 to fix this issue!

Hope this might help some other people with similar problems.